# Difference between "RenewDHCPLease()" and "IPConfig /renew"?

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I am using `RenewDHCPLease()` to renew the IP address of the system.

1. What is the exact difference between `RenewDHCPLease()` and `ipconfig /renew`?
2. Which one is better to use in Powershell?
3. Is it necessary to use `ReleaseDHCPLease()` before `RenewDHCPLease()`? If so why?

Below is my code:

```
try {
    $ips = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where { $_.IpEnabled -eq $true -and $_.DhcpEnabled -eq $true} -ErrorAction Stop
    if (!$ips) {
        Write-Output "`nDHCP is not Enabled on this system"
        Exit
    }
    foreach ($ip in $ips) { 
        Write-Output "`nRenewing IP Addresses" 
        $ip.RenewDHCPLease() | Out-Null  
        if ($?) {
            Write-Output "IP address has been renewed for this system"
        }
        else {
            Write-Error "IP Address Could not be renewed"
        }
    }
}
catch {
    $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Please review my answer and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`ReleaseDHCPLease` [releases the IP address bound to a specific DHCP enabled network adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/releasedhcplease-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration)
`RenewDHCPLease` [Renews the IP address on a specific DHCP enabled network adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/renewdhcplease-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration)

There is no need to use `ReleaseDHCPLease` before `RenewDHCPLease` since the old address is released and a new one is automatically acquired when using `RenewDHCPLease`

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IpEnabled=True AND DhcpEnabled=True' | Foreach-Object{
    $_.RenewDHCPLease() 
}
```

You could also use the `RenewDHCPLeaseAll` method to renew them all at once. Hope this helps :)